# Boost : Encountering compilation errors 'error: expected ';' after top level declarator namespace boost' and fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found

Tags: xcode, boost

Log : http://pastebin.com/NgNNNAM5

When compiling an Xcode  C++ project with boost, in C++ I encountered a number of errors when attempting to compile my unit test solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution : ensure that under the file inspector the unit test is set to c++ processed source, as Xcode has a nasty tendency to automatically set it to objective C. Changing this solved the original problems.